# Writing a large number of files in python, noticable slowdown at the end

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to write a large number of files [2000-2500] to disk after processing. I noticed that the first 100 or so images are fast to write to disk, then there is a slowdown. Why is this happening and what can I do to speed up the process?

This is my code that writes the images:

```
for b in range(Data.shape[1]):
    t0 = time.clock()
    img = Data[:,b]
    img = np.reshape(img,(501,501))

    save = os.path.join(savedir,"%s_%s"%(item,b))
    plt.imshow(img).figure.savefig(save)
    print "Saved %s of %s in %s seconds"%(b,Data.shape[1],time.clock()-t0)
```

Edit:

```
Saved 0 of 1024 in 0.103277 seconds
Saved 1 of 1024 in 0.0774039999999 seconds
Saved 2 of 1024 in 0.0883339999998 seconds
Saved 3 of 1024 in 0.0922500000001 seconds
Saved 4 of 1024 in 0.0972509999999 seconds
```

And after a few iterations:

```
Saved 1018 of 1024 in 2.152941 seconds
Saved 1019 of 1024 in 2.163633 seconds
Saved 1020 of 1024 in 2.198959 seconds
Saved 1021 of 1024 in 2.172303 seconds
Saved 1022 of 1024 in 2.19014 seconds
Saved 1023 of 1024 in 2.203727 seconds
```

Comment: Why are you using `plt.imshow(img).figure.savefig(save)` to write the data ? You are already using `print "Saving %s of %s"%(b,Data.shape[1])` for debugging process, I think you may use some other numpy method to write data.

Comment: can you add some more information - how do you know there is a slowdown? do you have profiling information? if so can you include a (small but relevant) snippet?

Comment: @scytale - Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you use `plt.imshow`, you create a new `AxesImage`, which will each take up some memory. To speed things up, you could clear the figure `clf()` after each save.

You can check this using `len(plt.gca().images)` to see how many images you have open. Without the `clf()` line, you will see than number growing by 1 each iteration.

```
for b in range(Data.shape[1]):
    img = Data[:,b]
    img = np.reshape(img,(501,501))
    print "Saving %s of %s"%(b,Data.shape[1])
    save = os.path.join(savedir,"%s_%s"%(item,b))
    plt.imshow(img).figure.savefig(save)
    print "There are %d image(s) open"%len(plt.gca().images)
    plt.gcf().clf() # clear the figure
```

Comment: Testing this. Will report in 10 minutes. The processing above the final save takes time to finish as well.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks